# Site optimisation - How to save a visitor site options?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'd like to learn how I'd save a users option to a MySQL database instead of using cookies to save this specific visitor data.

e.g.

On the landing page, is a red box 300 by 300 pixels, once the visitor hovers the Blue, Green, Yellow it'll switch  from red(default) to the color chosen.

How would I save this choice from an Offline user to database then if needed retrieve it?

```
+---------------------------+
|                           | - Blue
|           RED             | - Green
|                           | - Yellow
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: What's an "*offline* user"? `:S` Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: He means remote user.

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm.  My PHP is a bit rusty; someone should check it for SQL injection.

Comment: You can save the data, but you'll still need some way to link the data from the database with the user. I'm not sure how you can do that without using cookies.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, I see. I wouldn't recommend that particular tutorial btw. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated for the exact reason you mentioned. `mysqli_*` are the new functions.

Comment: Danny, I know PDO so I understand insert function quite well but is that truly the best way to do so?

Comment: Of course! How would you get data into a database without inserting it?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: PHP is a vast wasteland of sucky Internet tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use AJAX to communicate with your server and request it to store the settings to the database. You may use session to identify the user associated with the settings.

I assume you aren't trying to let users who aren't connected to the internet to save their settings.